# nodejs debugging memory leak with snapshots

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory-leaks, heap-dump

I have a memory leak in a git submodule of my nodejs app running built with express + mongoose + continuation-local-storage.

Using heapdump I am comparin snapshots from the beginning of the process with a snapshot from where it builds up ungarbaged objects.

However in my second snapshot I see the delta between snapshots for the String constructor is 131000 and just entries like this. Basically it's a stringified function. I have no clue why

```
"(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /** * @license 
* Lodash <https://lodash.com/> * Copyright JS Foundation and other 
contributors <https://js.foundation/> * Released under MIT license 
<https://lodash.com/license> * Based on Underscore.js 1.8.3 
<http://underscorejs.org/LICENSE> * Copyright Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud 
and Investigative Reporters & Editors */ ;(function() { /** Used as a safe 
reference for `undefined` in pre-ES5 environments. */ var undefined; /** Used 
as the semantic version number. */ var VERSION = '4.17.4'; /** Used as the 
size to enable large array optimizations. */ var LARGE_ARRAY_SIZE = 200; /** 
Error message constants. */ var CORE_ERROR_TEXT = 'Unsupported core-js use. 
Try https://npms.io/search?q=ponyfill.', FUNC_ERROR_TEXT = 'Expected a 
function'; /** Used to stand-in for `undefined` hash values. */ var 
HASH_UNDEFINED = '__lodash_hash_undefined__'; /** Used as the maximum memoize 
cache size. */ var MAX_MEMOIZE_SIZE" @252343
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like the lodash module being loaded.  Are you doing something that would cause lodash to get loaded thousands of times, but somehow bypassing the normal module cache?

Comment: No, not at all. But why is the function stringified?

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps it's handed off to `eval()` or `new Function()` to run it when the module is loaded?  They accept code as a JS string.  The start `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)` is a module wrapper so this is definitely from the loading of a module.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. However I am not patching the require, nore use babel (which as far as I know, patches the require)

Comment: Not much else we can do without knowing and analyzing your code.  If you have zillions of these identical module strings in the heap, then something is busted in the loader or in how you're using it because a module should only be loaded once and then cached from then on.

Comment: I know how the require works and see what you mean, thanks a lot. I guess I'll just do some more tests simply by eliminating code and profiling again